# How to create sub-users within the company registration in jhipster

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm new in jhipster development. I want to create sub-users within the company registration with one or more different Read/Write/Hidden permissions.
How to that in jhipster.Any suggestions or tutorial link for the same.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no users-and-"sub-users" system in the JHipster generated application. You can use users in different ROLEs.

You have to adapt the constants in `AuthoritiesConstants.java` used in Backend und Frontend. Search for the jhipster default `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_USER` in the generated Spring and Angular code (you'll find the constants in `SecurityConfiguration.java` and `*jhiHasAnyAuthority` in the Angular components and `authorities` in Angulars routing as well as in `authorities.csv`, `users_authorities.csv` and `users.csv` for the initial default setup of the database(s)).

In `UserService.java`'s `createUser()` you can change the default role for a JHipster user registration.

One good practical example can be found [here](https://github.com/Angular4JavaDevelopers/rfb-loyalty/issues/6) (which is from a [lesson on udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/angular-4-java-developers/learn/lecture/6156340)), but it's straightforward in JHipster.